# How to combine two tuples in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to combine two tuples, for example

My Tuples are:

```
(a,b)
(a,c)
(d,a)
(d,c)
```

I want the combination as,

```
(a,b,c)                // Ist & IInd tuple
(a,b,d)                // Ist & IIIrd tuple
(a,b,d,c)              // Ist & IVth tuple
(a,c,d)                // IInd & IIIrd tuple  ( IInd & IVth is also same)
```

Here I initially combine the first tuple with second tuple, third tuple and finally last tuple. Then I take the second tuple and combine it with third tuple and fourth tuple. Finally I take third tuple and combine it with the remaining last tuple. Remember If we combine two tuples, if the same combination values are occur, remove the duplicate tuples

Comment: Are you sure you want tuples instead of `Set` or `Seq`? The result you're describing is a heterogeneous collection if it's tuples. I don't think you're going to be able to get there without reflection.

Comment: Actually it is (String,String) format. I got these tuples after some operations

Comment: It's no problem that your inputs are tuples, but does the output need to be that way?

Comment: Are you sure that you need 2 different combinations (a,c,d) and (d,a,c)?

Comment: @Ashalynd If (a,c,d) is present then no need of (d,a,c)

Comment: this is really not what tuples are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is quite difficult with tuples if you want them as output. If a `set` will do then:

```
scala> List(('a,'b), ('a,'c), ('d,'a), ('d,'c)).combinations(2).map(
                                y => y.flatten(_.productIterator).toSet).toSet

res42: scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any]] = 
 Set(Set('a, 'b, 'c), Set('a, 'b, 'd), Set('a, 'b, 'd, 'c), Set('a, 'c, 'd))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... But it doesn't remove duplicate tuples,If I apply ur code result is  Set('a, 'b, 'c)
Set('a, 'b, 'd)
Set('a, 'b, 'd, 'c)
Set('a, 'c, 'd)
Set('a, 'c, 'd)
Set('d, 'a, 'c)      Set(a,c,d) is repeating

Answer (score 1):

Something like that might work

```
val tuples = List(('a','b'),('a','c'),('d','a'),('d','c'))

def combine (tuples: List[(Char,Char)]) = {
val combinations = for {
    t1<- tuples
    t2<- tuples
    if (t1!=t2)
} yield {
    Set(t1._1,t1._2,t2._1,t2._2).toList.sorted
combinations.toSet }
```

Comment: `for {
    t1<- tuples
    t2<- tuples.tail` doesn't work. As then you dont cover 2nd tuple with 3rd tuple. 2nd with 4th. 3rd with 4th etc. Moreover it doesn't give the desired output

Comment: See the author's comments. The desired output was actually not desired :) Agree with the comment regarding tail, that was not the way. Edited.